# JavaScript: text font for input value within table

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I can't seem to figure this one.

Using JS DOM:

```
var tr = document.createElement('tr');
var td = document.createElement('td');

var font = document.createElement('font');
font.setAttribute('color', 'red');

var input = document.createElement('input');
input.setAttribute('type', 'text');
input.setAttribute('value', document.createTextNode("TheText"));
font.appendChild(input);               

td.appendChild(font);
tr.appendChild(td);
CustTbody.appendChild(tr);
```

If you can't get it from the code,
I'm after a row of a table to be a text input box, with the value to be displayed in red.

I've tried in various forms, text inside the font tag, inside the input value. Didn't work.
Text inside the value, Input inside the Font. Didn't work.

**How** best to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `<font>` as it is obsolete now. Instead use `style` property to set the color.

```
input.style.color = "red"
```

Comment: That's It! I'll accept as answer when the timeout limit ends :) cheers